# Finding the result of a double Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We consider $s\ge 0$ a constant.

I want to calculate this integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left({-\frac{(q^2+p^2)}{2}}\right)\exp\left({-\frac{\left(\cosh(s)q+\sinh(s)p\right)^2+\left(\sinh(s)q+\cosh(s)p\right)^2}{2}}\right)dq\;dp$$

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: is it $\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}$?

Comment: My first thought it, *But why though?* Haha! In all seriousness, whence did this monster come‽

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ u=\cosh(s)q+\sinh(s)p, v=\sinh(s)q+\cosh(s)p $$
and then
$$ \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(p,q)}=\left|\begin{matrix}\sinh(s)&\cosh(s)\\
\cosh(s)&\sinh(s)
\end{matrix}\right|=-1 $$
and
$$ p=-\sinh(s)u+\cosh(s)v,q=\cosh(s)u-\sinh(s). $$
So
$$ p^2+q^2=[\sinh^2(s)+\cosh^2(s)](u^2+v^2) $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left({-\frac{(q^2+p^2)}{2}}\right)\exp\left({-\frac{\left(\cosh(s)q+\sinh(s)p\right)^2+\left(\sinh(s)q+\cosh(s)p\right)^2}{2}}\right)dq\;dp\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left({-\frac{[\sinh^2(s)+\cosh^2(s)](u^2+v^2)}{2}}\right)\exp\left({-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2}}\right)du\;dv\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left({-\frac{[\sinh^2(s)+\cosh^2(s)+1](u^2+v^2)}{2}}\right)du\;dv\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left({-\cosh^2(s)(u^2+v^2)}\right)du\;dv\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: and then what is $\int_{0}^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}ds\,da$? where $L$ is a constant. I find $0$ but Ithink its is false, please help me

Comment: @amine, start a new question and I will answer.

Comment: i post it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513932/calculation-of-an-integral