# calculation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to calculate $$\int_{0}^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}ds\,da$$ where $L$ is a constant.

I wrote:
$\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}=\frac{\pi\cosh(s)}{\cosh^2(s)}=\frac{\pi\cosh(s)}{1+\sinh^2(s)}$ and then use the change of variable $u=\sinh(s)$

But i find $0$ as aresult, i think that is false. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have two integrals. What have you tried for the second one?

Comment: this is what i wrote: $\int_0^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}ds\;da=\int_0^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi\cosh(s)}{\cosh^2(s)}ds\;da=\int_0^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi\cosh(s)}{1+\sinh^2(s)}ds\;da=\pi\int_0^L\int_{\sinh(a)}^{\sinh(L-a)}\frac{1}{1+u ^2}du\,da=\pi\int_0^L(L-2a)da=[La-a^2]_{0}^L=0$

Comment: I'm not sure what you did in the second to last step... It looks like you incorrectly took the integral of $\frac{1}{1+u^2}$.

Comment: i shoul take $[Argtan(x)]_{\sinh(a)}^{\sinh(L-a)}$ that gives what exacty?

Comment: the answer is not nice, but you should notice something special about it that lets you say what the second integral is without evaluating it. Try graphing it, perhaps.

Comment: Please give me more details, I am not able to find the result

Comment: Making the substitution $b = L-a$ is a short way to see it's $0$.

Comment: I did it with *Mathematica* and this is what I got
$$\int _a^{l-a}\int _0^l\frac{\pi }{\cosh (s)}da\,ds=-2 \pi  l \left(\arctan\left(\tanh \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)-\arctan\left(\tanh \left(\frac{l-a}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Raffaele, can you please give me the result of $\int _0^{l-a}\int _0^l\frac{\pi }{\cosh (s)}da\,ds$?

Answer (score 1):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi}{\cosh(s)}ds\,da\\
&=&\int_{0}^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{\pi\cosh(s)}{\cosh^2(s)}ds\,da\\
&=&\pi\int_{0}^L\int_{a}^{L-a}\frac{1}{1+\sinh^2(s)}d\sinh(s)\,da\\
&=&\pi\int_{0}^L\arctan(\sinh(s))\bigg|_a^{L-a} da\\
&=&\pi\int_{0}^L[\arctan(\sinh(L-a))-\arctan(\sinh(a))] da\\
&=&\pi\int_{0}^L\arctan(\sinh(L-a))da-\pi\int_0^L\arctan(\sinh(a))da\\
&=&\pi\int_{0}^L\arctan(\sinh(a))da-\pi\int_0^L\arctan(\sinh(a))da\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: And if we have at the bigining $\int_0^l\int_0^{l-a}$ that gives what as a result? Can as give exactly the expression of $\int_0^largtan(sinh(a))da$?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a more detailed answer here. As you calculated, we can evaluate the inside integral as

$$\int_0^L\int_a^{L-a}\frac{1}{\cosh(s)}\,ds\,da=\int_0^L\int_{\sinh(a)}^{\sinh(L-a)}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du\,da=\int_0^L(\arctan(\sinh(L-a))-\arctan(\sinh(a))\,da$$

At this point you might wonder if we can even take this next antiderivative... The answer is we don't need to. If you graphed this function, you might notice that it's odd about $L/2$. If we shift the integral by letting

$$x=a-\frac{L}{2}$$

and write

$$\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^\frac{L}{2}(\arctan(\sinh(\frac{L}{2}-x))-\arctan(\sinh(\frac{L}{2}+x))\,dx$$

The integrand

$$I(x)=\arctan(\sinh(\frac{L}{2}-x))-\arctan(\sinh(\frac{L}{2}+x)$$

is now an odd function. You can verify $I(-x)=-I(x)$. Our integral is over a symmetric region, and our integrand is odd. This means the total integral must evaluate to $0$. Therefore,

$$\int_0^L\int_a^{L-a}\frac{1}{\cosh(s)}\,ds\,da=0$$